# Java: Recursive methods for heap ADT operations

Tags: java, recursion, heap

I have 2 iterative methods used in my heap implementation, one called `reheapUp`(for enqueue), one called `reheapDown`(for dequeue) and a helper method called `newhole` which manipulates the hole in the heap structure used in the reheapUp/reheapDown methods.

I'm trying to make a recursive versions of reheapUp/reheapDown but I keep running into a variety of issues, namely stack overflows. I've tried different approaches but have not had much luck. Here are the iterative versions, followed by my latest attempt at a recursive reheapDown, called `recReheapdown`:

```
private void reheapUp(T element)
  // Current lastIndex position is empty.
  // Inserts element into the tree and ensures shape and order properties.
  {
    int hole = lastIndex;
    while ((hole > 0)    // hole is not root and element > hole's parent
           &&                                               
      (element.compareTo(elements.get((hole - 1) / 2)) > 0)) 
      {
      // move hole's parent down and then move hole up
      elements.set(hole,elements.get((hole - 1) / 2)); 
      hole = (hole - 1) / 2;                                
    }
    elements.set(hole, element);  // place element into final hole
  }

private void reheapDown(T element)
  // Current root position is "empty";
  // Inserts element into the tree and ensures shape and order properties.
  {
    int hole = 0;      // current index of hole
    int newhole;       // index where hole should move to

    newhole = newHole(hole, element);   // find next hole
    while (newhole != hole)
    {
      elements.set(hole,elements.get(newhole));  // move element up
      hole = newhole;                            // move hole down
      newhole = newHole(hole, element);          // find next hole
    }
    elements.set(hole, element);           // fill in the final hole
  }
```

And finally:

```
private void recReheapDown(T element)
    {
      int hole = 0;      // current index of hole
      int newhole;   // index where hold should move to

      newhole = newHole(hole, element); //find next hole

      if(newhole == hole)//base condition
      {
        elements.set(hole, element); //fill in the final hole
        return;
      }

      elements.set(hole,elements.get(newhole));
      hole = newhole; //move hole down

      recReheapDown(element);
    }
```

My `recReheapUp` is similar, so I won't post it. I would appreciate it greatly if someone could help me solve this problem. I've never been great at recursion, but i'm doing my best to learn. If someone would like to see the `newHole` method ill post it in an edit.

Lastly (just because i'm curious) what would be the complexity differences between the iterative and recursive versions? Thanks.

EDIT: Here is the newHole method as requested.

```
private int newHole(int hole, T element)
  // If either child of hole is larger than element, return the index
  // of the larger child; otherwise, return the index of hole.
  {
    int left = (hole * 2) + 1;
    int right = (hole * 2) + 2;

    if (left > lastIndex)
      // hole has no children
      return hole;         
    else
    if (left == lastIndex)
      // hole has left child only
      if (element.compareTo(elements.get(left)) < 0)             
        // element < left child
        return left;
      else
        // element >= left child
        return hole;
    else
    // hole has two children 
    if (elements.get(left).compareTo(elements.get(right)) < 0)
      // left child < right child
      if (elements.get(right).compareTo(element) <= 0)
        // right child <= element
        return hole;
      else
        // element < right child
        return right;
    else
    // left child >= right child
    if (elements.get(left).compareTo(element) <= 0)
      // left child <= element
      return hole;
    else
      // element < left child
      return left;
  }
```

Comment: Have you single-stepped this in the debugger? It looks to me like your stack overflow is caused by you calling `recReheapDown` with the same value every time. I *think* you want `recReheapDown(newhole);` As far as computational complexity is concerned, the recursive versions will be the same as the non-recursive versions: O(log n) worst case. The iterative versions will likely run slightly faster, and they won't be subject to stack overflow when you have *huge* heaps.

Comment: Thanks, ill give it a shot and hopefully it works. I appreciate the input, I've been struggling w this for a few days now.

Comment: Because of the generic argument, it's not letting me use it this way. So i'll have to figure something out...

Comment: My mistake. I didn't notice that. Please post your 'newHole' method. Seriously, you should single step your code in the debugger. You'll find the problem pretty quickly that way. If you don't know how to use the debugger, this is the perfect time to learn.

Comment: I will post it. yeah I'm not great w the debugger, I usually just brute force problem solve when things aren't working lol. Thanks so much for trying to help me though, I very much appreciate it.